# AngularFire2 Auth Register - Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, angular5, angularfire2

I followed [this tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/multi-step-signup-firebase-email-password-auth-angular-reactive-forms/) to build an Register form that allows to add aditional data to the user object.

I changed some stuff because i need a 1 step registration form. There is for me no reason to do a secondary step just for adding a username.

Here is my Model:

```
export class UserModel implements UserInterface.Root {
    uid: string;
    email: string;
    displayName: string;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    photoURL?: string;

    constructor(user) {
        this.uid = user.uid;
        this.email = user.email;
        this.displayName = user.displayName;
        this.firstName = user.firstName  || 'No first name';
        this.lastName = user.lastName  || 'No last name';
        this.photoURL = user.photoURL;
    }
}
```

Here is my auth.service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    user: Observable<UserModel>;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
                private afs: AngularFirestore,
                private router: Router,
                private notify: NotifyService) {

        this.user = this.afAuth.authState
            .switchMap(user => {
                if (user) {
                    return this.afs.doc<UserModel>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
                } else {
                    return Observable.of(null);
                }
            });

    }

    //// Email/Password Auth ////
    emailSignUp(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(user => {
                return this.setUserDoc(user); // create initial user document
            })
            .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
    }

    // Update properties on the user document
    updateUser(user: UserModel, data: any) {
        return this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).update(data);
    }

    // Sets user data to firestore after succesful login
    private setUserDoc(user) {

        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserModel> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

        const data: UserModel = {
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email || null,
            photoURL: user.photoURL || 'url to default image',
            displayName: user.displayName,
            firstName: user.firstName || 'No first name',
            lastName: user.lastName || 'No last name'
        };

        return userRef.set(data);

    }
}
```

And here the register.componentts with the signUp Function that trigger the error:

```
export class SiteAuthRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    signUpForm: FormGroup;

    userState;

    constructor(public auth: AuthService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.userState = this.auth.user.map(user => {
            if (user) {
                return user.displayName ? 'complete' : 'incomplete';
            }
        });

        this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
            'email': ['', [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.email
            ]],
            'displayName': ['', [
                Validators.required
            ]],
            'password': ['', [
                Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'),
                Validators.minLength(6),
                Validators.maxLength(25)
            ]]
        });

    }


    // Using getters will make your code look pretty
    get email() {
        return this.signUpForm.get('email');
    }

    get password() {
        return this.signUpForm.get('password');
    }

    get displayName() {
        return this.signUpForm.get('displayName');
    }

    signUp() {
        return this.auth.emailSignUp(this.email.value, this.password.value).then((user) => {
                console.log(user);
                return this.auth.updateUser(new UserModel(user), {
                    displayName: this.displayName.value
                });
            }
        );
    }

}
```

register.component.html

```
<section class="site-register dark-theme">
    <div class="site-register-inner">

        <mat-card class="auth-wrapper">

            <div class="auth-brand">
                <div class="auth-brand-inner">
                    <img src="/assets/animesector-logo.svg" alt="Logo">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="auth-form" *ngIf="(auth.user | async) || {} as user">
                <h1>Create Account</h1>

                <form [formGroup]="signUpForm" *ngIf="!user.uid" (ngSubmit)="signUp()">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" formControlName="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="!signUpForm.controls['email'].valid && signUpForm.controls['email'].touched">
                            No Idea... This Shit is complicated
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Benutzername" formControlName="displayName">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="!signUpForm.controls['displayName'].valid && signUpForm.controls['displayName'].touched">
                            Please enter a valid displayName
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="!signUpForm.controls['password'].valid && signUpForm.controls['password'].touched">
                            Please enter a valid email Password
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!signUpForm.valid">Sign Up</button>
                </form>

                <!--
                <form [formGroup]="detailForm" *ngIf="user.uid && !user.displayName" (ngSubmit)="setDisplayName(user)">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="displayName" formControlName="displayName">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="!detailForm.controls['displayName'].valid && detailForm.controls['displayName'].touched">
                            Please enter a valid displayName
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!detailForm.valid">Sign Up</button>
                </form>


                <div class="registration-success" *ngIf="user.displayName">
                    Your have completed the registration!
                </div> -->

                <footer>
                    <p>Mit deiner Registrierung akzeptierst du die  <a href="/#">AGB</a> und <a href="/#">Datenschutzerklärung</a> von animesector</p>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <p>Hast du bereits einen Account? <a [routerLink]="'/login'">Einloggen</a></p>
                </footer>
            </div>

        </mat-card>

    </div>
</section>
```

Inside the signUp function the console.log(user); return an undefined. but i dont understand why. the emailSignUp return a promise or not?

At last i get this console error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
    at new UserModel (user.model.ts:10)
    at eval (site-auth-register.component.ts:65)
    at e.g (auth.js:23)
    at Yb (auth.js:26)
    at Ub (auth.js:26)
    at z.h.Qb (auth.js:25)
    at Cb (auth.js:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
```

Comment: Did you try with default user value in the constructor : `constructor(user = {})` ?

Comment: in the register.component.ts? yes i do. I define it over the constructor with public user = {} Also tryed in constructor after you telled me, but didnt work also. I Uptedet my post with the html file. there is a *ngIf="(auth.user | async) || {} as user"

I also do now a stackblitz. that makes it easyer for you to help me.

Comment: Was talking about the user.model.ts where the error has been thrown. Did you try to debug ? The angularfire2 can't know about your custom constructor, you may need to create a non args constructor.

Comment: So you mean i cant use the UserModel for the register.component? I Try to debug sience 3 days. Im new in programming. im normaly a frontend designer.

Comment: You don't need to use constructor to create an object with javascript, this is a UserModel Object : `{
 uid: user.uid,
 email: user.email,
 displayName: user.displayName,
 firstName: user.firstName || 'No first name',
 lastName: user.lastName || 'No last name',
 photoURL: user.photoURL
}
`

Comment: But why the console.log(user); in the signUp() function returns a "undifined"? Normaly i must get back the user arraythere or not?